# InDesign: how to export PDF with fit to page

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf, export

I'm creating a PDF publication for onscreen reading where readers should be able to page through by hitting the PGDN key. I know enough to select `Layout:  Single Page` in the `Viewing` section of the `General` page of the `Export Adobe PDF` dialog.  However, the resulting PDF needs two PGDN pushes to turn the page; the first scrolls the page slightly down, and then the second actually turns the page.  Meanwhile, I've seen many other nice PDFs made with InDesign where a single PGDN turns the page.  I suspect my problem has something to do with my page size (A5) or top/bottom margin sizes, but I'm not sure.

Comment: You need to have the entire page visible in your PDF reader for that to work. If only the top part of the page is visible, page down will always scroll down to show the bottom part before jumping to the next page. That's intentional, and anything else would be extremely annoying to the user. Doesn't matter whether the PDF is exported from InDesign or not. The default view in Acrobat/Reader is to fit the width of the page to the width of the viewport; just hit Ctrl/Cmd + 0 to fit the entire page instead. In Acrobat you can save this view in the PDF; don't think you can directly in InDesign.

Comment: yes, this is a PDF setting, not an InDesign setting.

Comment: I am using CS6 but i googled and apparently they did add this via the export dialog in newer CC versions. See my answer below. Yes, its a PDF setting, but you can set it when exporting from ID (CC).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the 'Viewing → View' to 'Fit Page' or 'Fit Height' or '100%'. Try and see which one works for you. In any case you need to look at the 'View' options, not the 'Layout' options. See [this](http://www.tech4pub.com/2015/07/14/indesign-cc-tip-pdf-export-view-options/) article.

*note: apparently this was added in CC and may not be available in older InDesign versions*

[image]

Comment: Tried "Fit Page," worked perfectly.  Thank you!!